# Call to undefined method Laravel\Lumen\Application::configurationIsCached()

Tags: lumen

I Just install lumen-passport using

> composer require [dusterio/lumen-passport](https://github.com/dusterio/lumen-passport)

then after just running `php artisan`

I got this In `PassportServiceProvider.php line 81:`

```
Call to undefined method Laravel\Lumen\Application::configurationIsCached()
```

have you encounter the same?

What did you do to solve it?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is related to this [Passport 7.3.2 issue](https://github.com/dusterio/lumen-passport/issues/106).
The solution is to downgrade to `laravel/passport` to version `7.3.1`

Answer (score 0):

Not a good idea but i think the issue is related to new release so for the main time for me to be able to execute php artisan command I just comment this lines

```
if (! $this->app->configurationIsCached()) {
    $this->mergeConfigFrom(__DIR__.'/../config/passport.php', 'passport');
}
```

then good to go.. after that uncomment again

Answer (score 0):

Another way to solve this is by using a laravel/lumen version above 5.8.11. Where the [`configurationIsCached`](https://github.com/laravel/lumen-framework/commit/7e3ece68667d6fe1914fdc2d9c028a9a1e6b8a88) method has been added.